# I couldn't go through Middleware in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-socialite

I use Laravel Socialite to make login function, I wanna check if not exsisting email in database then go to register form, if email exist then login but i cannot go through middleware although I write dd(Auth::check()) and it return true, please help, thanks so much

My route:

```
    // USER LOGIN
    Route::get('', 'UserController@login')->name('login');
    Route::post('login', 'UserController@loginProcess')->name('user.login.process');

    route::group([
        'middleware' => 'auth:user',
    ], function () {
        Route::get('home','UserPageController@index')->name('user.home.index');
        Route::post('home','UserSelectController@selectedCity')->name('user.home.selectedcity');
        Route::get('select','UserSelectController@index')->name('user.select.index');
    });

    // Test
    Route::get('test', 'TestController@index')->name('test');
    Route::get('test2', 'TestController@socialLogin')->name('social.login');
    Route::get('register', 'TestController@register')->name('register');
```

my TestController:

```
    public function socialLogin()
    {
        return view('user.test.social-login');
    }

    public function callback($provider): RedirectResponse
    {
        $data = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

        $user = User::query()
            ->where('email', $data->getEmail())
            ->first();
        if (is_null($user)) {
            $user        = new User();
            $user_email = $data->getEmail();
            return redirect()->route('register')->with([
                'user_email' => $user_email,
            ]);
        } else {
           $user_id = $user->id;
           Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);
           return redirect()->route('user.home.index');
        }
    }
```

my UserController:

```
    public function loginProcess(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email|exists:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:4',
        ]);


        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');


        if (auth('user')->attempt($credentials, false)) {
            return redirect()->route('user.home.index');
        } else {
            return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Email or password are wrong.']);
        }
    }
```

and my /config/auth.php:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'user',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'user',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'user' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'user',
        // ],
    ],
```

Is there any way to go through Middleware, please help

Comment: Change middleware to `'middleware' => ['auth:user'],`

Comment: I tried but it still did not work

Comment: since you want your middleware to use the guard `user` (`'middleware' => 'auth:user',`) then you should login the user using that same guard instead of the default `web` (`Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);`) so change it to `Auth::guard('user')->loginUsingId($user_id);` or `auth('user')->loginUsingId($user_id);`